# Facebook like button does not marked as liked after logging in

Tags: html, facebook, api

Just a quick question.
Here is a Facebook article with an embedded FB like button at the bottom: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs

When I am logged out of Facebook, I am clicking Like button -> popup for Logging in appeared -> I enter credentials and successfully logging in.
But the number of likes has not increased and button has not changed to "clicked"/"liked" state, so I should click it one more time.

Is it expected?
Can it be changed or configured somehow to trigger some kind of click event just after logging in?

Regards.

Comment: No, that is not expected. I don't think you need to click it one more time after logging in throught the popup. Did you try refreshing after that? Are you having difficulties in your Internet connection?

Comment: Hi @ParamSiddharth , yes, I tried to reload the page and nothing changed. Internet connection is stable. Aren't you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I think I am not able to understand why it isn't updating, though you must know that this behaviour is not expected and after liking, the button must update its status.